# How can I get the type an object in a generic list assigned to an abstract class in C#?

Tags: c#, object, generic-list

```
System.Generic.List<BaseBlock> BlockList = new System.Generic.List<BaseBlock>();
```

`BaseBlock` is an abstract class. Later in the program I add some objects to the list. Knowing the index of the object, how can I get the specific (not abstract) type / class of it?

Comment: Test/homework question?

Comment: No. It is not a test / homework question.

Answer (score 1):

> Knowing the index of the object, how can I get the specific (not abstract) type / class of it?

To find the actual type of the object at index `i` use

```
Type t = BlockList[i].GetType();
```

`GetType` gives you the *actual* type of an object, regardless of the type of variable or container it's in.

Comment: How do I get a static property of the class / type?

Comment: @MimiKal - seriously?

Comment: @MimiKal That's a completely different question, and it has [many answers](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+get+static+property) on this site.

Comment: @Igor if you feel it's a basic question that has been asked and answered before why don't you provide links to documentation or other answers instead of belittling the question?  Everyone has to learn somewhere.

Comment: Sorry. I thought D Stanley would include that in his answer.

Comment: @DStanley - I help where I can but I have very little patience for questions where I can, with 100% certainty, say that the OP did not even attempt to search for the answer with SO or even on Google. Just putting the above question (in the comments) as is in the Google search engine yields pages of useful results. Add the word c# and the results are even better. Also you can look at my answer and comment history, I am not one to belittle anyone.

Comment: @MimiKal Your question made no mention of static methods so I don't know why you expected an answer to address that.  Do some research on your own and come back with a new question if you're still stuck.